# android : how to detect zoom in and zoom out gesture detect after pointer up here is my code

Tags: android

**android : how to detect zoom in and zoom out gesture detect after pointer up here is my code**

**Here is my code**

```
private var initialDistance = 0.toDouble()
private var lastDistance = 0.toDouble()
private var ZOOM_IN = false
private var ZOOM_OUT = false

if (event.pointerCount > 1) {
      
        val action = event.action
        when (action and event.actionMasked) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN -> {
                val x1 = event.getX(0).toDouble()
                val y1 = event.getY(0).toDouble()
                val x2 = event.getX(1).toDouble()
                val y2 = event.getY(1).toDouble()

                initialDistance = sqrt((x2 - x1).pow(2.0) - (y2 - y1).pow(2.0))

            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                val x1 = event.getX(0).toDouble()
                val y1 = event.getY(0).toDouble()
                val x2 = event.getX(1).toDouble()
                val y2 = event.getY(1).toDouble()

                lastDistance = sqrt((x2 - x1).pow(2.0) - (y2 - y1).pow(2.0))

                if (lastDistance > initialDistance)
                    ZOOM_OUT = true
                else
                    ZOOM_IN = true
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP -> {
                
                if (ZOOM_IN) zoomIn()
                if (ZOOM_OUT) zoomOut()
            }
        }
```

is this a right formula to measure two pointer distance ?

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use **ScaleGestureDetector** for pinch zoom. it's pretty forward.
I use this for zooming

```
ScaleGestureDetector(this, object : ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener {

        override fun onScale(p0: ScaleGestureDetector?): Boolean {
                        scaleFactor = detector.scaleFactor
                        scaleFactor = if (scaleFactor < 1) 1 else scaleFactor 

                        scaleFactor = ((scaleFactor * 100) as Int).toFloat() / 100 

                        view.setScaleX(scaleFactor)
                        view.setScaleY(scaleFactor)

            return true
        }

        override fun onScaleBegin(p0: ScaleGestureDetector?): Boolean {
            return true
        }

        override fun onScaleEnd(p0: ScaleGestureDetector?) {
        }
    })
```